# Как повторять текст в документе. после окончания строк

Tags: python

Мне нужно, чтобы в этом коде после того, как закончился текст, не писались пустые строчки, а повторялся текст, написанный в документе

```
import keyboard, time

def startSpam():
    keyboard.write(file.readline(), delay=0.000000001)
    keyboard.press("Enter")

time.sleep(5)
file = open("C:\\Users\\Matvey\\Desktop\\SpamMsg.txt", "r", encoding='UTF-8')
while True:
    startSpam()
```

Comment: попробуй попонятнее описать проблему

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачитать файл в список и крутиться по нему.

```
import keyboard, time

def startSpam():
    for line in lines:
        keyboard.write(line, delay=0.000000001)
        keyboard.press("Enter")

time.sleep(5)
file = open("C:\\Users\\Matvey\\Desktop\\SpamMsg.txt", "r", encoding='UTF-8')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
while True:
    startSpam()
```

Или по окончанию файла перематывать на его начало.

```
import keyboard, time

def startSpam():
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        file.seek(0)
        line = file.readline()
    keyboard.write(line, delay=0.000000001)
    keyboard.press("Enter")

time.sleep(5)
file = open("C:\\Users\\Matvey\\Desktop\\SpamMsg.txt", "r", encoding='UTF-8')
while True:
    startSpam()
```

Comment: Только в первом случае лучше всё же использовать `with open` для красоты

Comment: Хм... отмечу, что цикл while  в данном случае бесконечен. Исходя из названия функции, код предназначен для спама. Все вместе дает код, который может принести ущерб... Пожалуйста, не делайте такие вещи.

Comment: @A_Vaclav Так то да, но может человек просто учится на таком примере. Когда явно что-то вредоносное делают, тогда да, тогда лучше не помогать, тут просто сообщение на экране )

Comment: Так. В этом примере изучается работа с файлами, например? Или явно указывают на цель - "Мне нужно, чтобы в этом коде после того, как закончился текст, не писались пустые строчки, а повторялся текст, написанный в документе"?
А В самом коде имя функции не указывает на предназначение? @CrazyElf

Comment: Не подменяйте понятия. Loop  это цикл, а spam - это спам. Не ленились бы и дополнили свой ответ "Предупреждение: это может привести к не хорошим делам. Таким и таким..." @GrAnd

Answer (score 0):

Или можно сделать так:

```
import keyboard, time

def startSpam():
    keyboard.write(text, delay=0.000000001)
    keyboard.press("Enter")

time.sleep(5)
file = open("C:\\Users\\Matvey\\Desktop\\SpamMsg.txt", "r", encoding='UTF-8')
text = file.read() # Читаем весь текст сразу

while True:
    startSpam()
```